Highlighting the cursor line in Vim?
I would like to have the line with the cursor in it, known as cursor line to be highlighted as heavily as possible. The 15-years-old topic was informative for me: How to correctly highlight cursor line in VIM? as :set cursorline works for me mostly, it draws 3px line among all the display inside of console window.
But I was unable to get any visible result from :hi cursorline and :hi specialkey using Vim 9.0 on Linux laptop. The most desirable highlighting for me is changing the font size, but changing any font characteristics or line margins is interesting for me.
Where can I read the list of possible styles for the cursor line?

Not sure what that 3px line you mention is. Anyway, see :help highlight-ctermbg and :help highlight-ctermfg for color attributes, :help highlight-term for typographic attributes.

Font size is defined by the terminal Vim runs in. There's no way to change the font size of a single line in TUI Vim.
